# Perl: parse through multiple files in a single SSH session in File::Remote

Tags: perl

I am making a script in Perl using the File::Remote module. The script needs to parse through several files in several hosts (let's say about 3 files per host). However, every time I open a file, the script connects to the host via SSH. My code looks like the following:

```
my $secure = new File::Remote(rsh => '/usr/bin/ssh', rcp => '/usr/bin/scp');
foreach $host (@hostList)
{
    for ($number = 1; $number < 4; $number++)
    {
        my $logFile = "log_$number.log";
        $secure->open(HANDLE, "$host:/home/$logFile") or die;

        ...
    }
}
```

So if I have 4 hosts in the @hostList array, the script would attempt 12 SSH connections (the total number of files to parse through). However I found this to be inefficient and I was wondering if I can make it so that it needs to perform an SSH connection only once per host or SSH session (so in this case, a total of 4 SSH connections). Does such an option exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach $host (@hostlist) {
    @files = map { "/home/log_$_.log" } 1 .. 3;
    open HANDLE, "/usr/bin/ssh $host cat @files |";
    # ... process HANDLE ...
}
```

(assumes remote system has `cat`, filenames have no spaces or other shell metacharacters, etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this piece of code! Two more questions: one, is there a way to suppress output of the cat commands (like, say some of the files are missing, the console would say that the files are missing; I'd rather not have these appear on the screen). Second, what does that vertical bar at the end of the command do?

Comment: One: `"/usr/bin/ssh $host cat @files 2>/dev/null |"`

Two: It means to take the output from the command (that precedes the pipe) and make the output of the command available in `HANDLE`.  The more modern way to write this is  `open HANDLE, "|-", COMMAND` but I often use the old way because I can't always remember whether that second argument should be "|-" or "-|".

Comment: Oh, okay. One more thing. Instead of simply discarding the error messages, is it possible to store it into a scalar in the Perl script I'm running (so that I may log the error instead of blindly parsing away). I'm not sure if you can do that in a Linux command but I'm still a novice in Perl, so who knows?

Comment: Never mind, I just decided to redirect the output so that it appends to the same log file that I'm logging to :p Oh silly me, but it would be nice to know if what I asked in the above post is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign):

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

for my $host (...) {
    my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, autodie => 1);
    for my $number (1..3) {
        my $fh = $sftp->open("/home/log_$number.log");
        ...
    }

    # or
    $sftp->mget("/home/log_*.log", $local_path);
 }
```

Or using [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH%3a%3aParallel) you can even retrieve the files from all the host in parallel:

```
use Net::OpenSSH::Parallel;
$pssh = Net::OpenSSH::Parallel->new;
$pssh->add_host($_) for @hosts;
$pssh->push('*', 'scp_get', { glob => 1 }, "/home/log_*.log", "$local_path/%HOST%/");
$pssh->run;
```